# How to add multiple historic data to GoogleFit

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I want to add historic training data consisting of training type / device, start / end time, power, puls, cycles per min, kilo calories. But all true the google fit history API uses data sets it seems that you can only add one datapoint at a time using `com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData`. But that would not add up to a training session.

Is that true or did I misunderstand / overlooked something in the API.

PS: since there is always someone asking for code (even on a theoretical question like this) I committed a snapshot to [github](https://github.com/krischik/Fit-Import). The most interesting file would be [GoogleFIT.kt](https://github.com/krischik/Fit-Import/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com.krischik/fit_import/GoogleFIT.kt). Of course the source is pretty much work in progress and not written ind Java but Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own questing again: You need to use a `com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Session` and `com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.SessionInsertRequest` to combine the data and then add them with `com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.SessionsApi.insertSession`.

A rather complex work but you can find a working version in [GoogleFIT.kt](https://github.com/krischik/Fit-Import/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com.krischik/fit_import/GoogleFIT.kt). Look for the `insertTraining` method.